# How do I get responses in Google Forms to automatically be updated when updating the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I'm in a situation, where I have been given a source of information, with all sorts of people. And with that, I wish to insert all this inside of Google Forms, in the response section. And so I was wondering, if I could simply insert all this inside of the spreadsheet, for the response destination. 
Is this possible, and how could I do it?

Comment: Welcome. Please see if you can edit your answer and provide a link to a sample spreadsheet or/and form. Your question is quite vague. Also please read [ask] and [About asking](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: not possible...

Answer (score -1):

i know this is an old post but this answer is for anyone else looking for the same solution to a similar problem quite recently.
I did something similar recently- auto populating & auto updating a google form with data values from the google sheet after a response has been submitted, here is the working live sample form: